# Power BI - minimal table for exclusive and full values

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table that looks like this

[image]

where column *exclusive* contains column names (from a, b, c) based on their column importance symbolised with '>': *a* > *b* > *c*

For example, if columns *a*, *b*, *c* all have a value (like in row 5) then *a* is chosen for the exclusive value because it is the most important - and when *b* & *c* have a value in the same row, *b* gets selected.  *c* only gets selected when *a* and *b* both don't have a value.

From this we can plot a chart like this

[image]

**Question**
Is it possible with DAX, to also create a chart like this from the same table, which contains the sum of the value column for each of *a*, *b*, *c* columns independent of the other columns?:

[image]

My current solution involves repeating data which increases the data size without increasing information content - and so I'd like to avoid it.

Like this table:

[image]

This table allows me to generate both charts, the latter by using the *full* and *value* columns.  The former chart by filtering on *is_exclusive* and using *exclusive* with *value* columns.

As an advanced bonus, could I do the all the above and have variable importance?  So for example, choose c > b > a or any combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Measure similar to this:

```
By Column = 
  SWITCH(SELECTEDVALUE(YourTable[exclusive]),
    "a", CALCULATE(SUM(YourTable[value]), REMOVEFILTERS('YourTable'[exclusive]), YourTable[a] = 1),
    "b", CALCULATE(SUM(YourTable[value]), REMOVEFILTERS('YourTable'[exclusive]), YourTable[b] = 1),
    "c", CALCULATE(SUM(YourTable[value]), REMOVEFILTERS('YourTable'[exclusive]), YourTable[c] = 1)
  )
```

Then use `[exclusive]` for X-axis, and the new measure for the Values.

Ideally, you would have a separate table for the a, b, c - or categories.
Example:
Table: `Dim Category`

| Category |
| --- |
| a |
| b |
| c |

And then you would use this for your chart X-axis, with the measure updated to:

```
By Column = 
  SWITCH(SELECTEDVALUE(`Dim Category`[Category]),
    "a", CALCULATE(SUM(YourTable[value]), YourTable[a] = 1),
    "b", CALCULATE(SUM(YourTable[value]), YourTable[b] = 1),
    "c", CALCULATE(SUM(YourTable[value]), YourTable[c] = 1)
  )
```

And for completeness - you can have this measure for the first chart:

```
By Exclusivity = 
  var thisCat = SELECTEDVALUE(`Dim Category`[Category])
  return CALCULATE( SUM(YourTable[value]), YourTable[exclsuive] = thisCat )
```

Comment: For the bonus part with variable importance - will there only be three categories or more? Would the end report user select/change or something for report authors to play around with?

Comment: The actual number is around 10 categories.